# Two mutually perpendicular vectors

Tags: vectors

I cannot demonstrate this excersice about vectors:
If $A$ and $B$ are mutually perpendicular vectors( different to zero vector) and "c" is any number show that :

$\|A +cB \| \geq \|A\|$.

Well I don´t know where to start, I was thinking about using the dot product but I don´t get how to use it, could anyone give me a solution or any idea?

Comment: You know that $\|V\| = V \cdot V$ where $V\cdot V$ is the dot product of $V$ with itself, right? DId you try using that rule to rewrite both sides of the equation?

Answer (score 2):

You need only note that
\begin{align*}
(A+cB, A+cB) &= (A, A) + c^2(B, B) + 2c^2(A, B)\\
&= (A, A) + c^2(B, B)\\
&\ge (A, A).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\left\|A+cB\right\|^2=\left\|A\right\|^2+|c|^2\left\|B\right\|^2$$

Comment: Don't forget about the factor of $c$.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks, good catch.